# Rendering circles on none retina displays

Tags: ios, render, geometry

I have collection view. Items - is a view with 2 circles - circle views for select and for mark. Some of my views rendering not correct. I work on views frame and made changes: all floating values are integers now. Its help for retina displays. What can i do for non-retina displays?

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect frame, contentFrame, markFrame, selectFrame;
    int markFrameMargin, contentHeight, selectRadius, markRadius;

    frame = self.frame;
    frame.origin.x = (int) frame.origin.x;
    frame.origin.y = (int) frame.origin.y;
    frame.size.width = (int) frame.size.width;
    frame.size.height = (int) frame.size.height;
    self.frame = frame;

    contentHeight = (int) self.bounds.size.height * ContentFrameRatio + 1;
    CGRectDivide(self.bounds, &contentFrame, &markFrame, contentHeight, CGRectMinYEdge);

    selectFrame = contentFrame;
    markFrame   = CGRectInset(markFrame, (markFrame.size.width - markFrame.size.height) / 2, 0);

    markFrameMargin = (int) markFrame.size.width / MarkFrameMarginRatio;
    markFrame = CGRectInset(markFrame, markFrameMargin, markFrameMargin);

    selectRadius = selectFrame.size.width / 2;
    markRadius   = markFrame.size.width / 2;

    self.contentLabel.frame = contentFrame;
    self.selectedBackgroundView.frame = selectFrame;
    self.markView.frame = markFrame;

    self.selectedBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = selectRadius;
    self.markView.layer.cornerRadius = markRadius;
}
```

Screen:

[image]

I am find the solve. For good circle rendering be sure that:

1. Position of frame are integer values
2. Width and Height are integer
3. Width and Height are even ( width % 2 == 0 )

Comment: `CGRectIntegral` may be an easier way of rounding your frame values.

Comment: Thnx u. I know about it, but this method don't make position values to integer.

Comment: At a wild guess it looks like    selectRadius = selectFrame.size.width / 2; is coming back with a non-integer value. Have you tried sizing the frame so its width is an even number? Also make sure the width and height are the same or the circle will look odd.

Comment: Problem already solved. But thnx u for answer.
"selectRadius = selectFrame.size.width / 2;"
select radius has type "int" than it always integer.

Comment: @user2979568 `CGRectIntegral: Returns the smallest rectangle that results from converting the source rectangle values to integers.`

Comment: @James P
`CGRect someFrame = CGRectMake(0.5, 0.5, 1.2, 1.3); someFrame = CGRectIntegral(someFrame); NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f", someFrame.origin.x, someFrame.origin.y, someFrame.size.width, someFrame.size.height);`
***0.000000 0.000000 2.000000 2.000000***
Yes, u right, but look at that: 
`CGRect someFrame = CGRectMake(0.5, 0.9, 1.9, 10.8); someFrame = CGRectIntegral(someFrame); NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f", someFrame.origin.x, someFrame.origin.y, someFrame.size.width, someFrame.size.height);`
***0.000000 0.000000 3.000000 12.000000***